# About the useage of python math.floor()

Tags: python-3.x

I used python math.floor() for calculations but found that it was different from what I thought more. The code is as follows:

```
import math
x=math.floor(-4.1)**math.floor(-3.1)**math.floor(2.1)
y=-5**-4**2
print(x,y)
```

Why are the operation results of x and Y are not the same?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include your code as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image. 
[Why do we hate screenshots so much?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/) Your question was fine before you revised it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `-a**n` and `(-a)**n` are not the same. The first becomes `-(a**n)`.

So when you write `-5**...` and `math.floor(-4.1)**...` they are not the same either.

---

If we fix this we get:

```
>>> x=math.floor(-4.1)**math.floor(-3.1)**math.floor(2.1)
>>> y=(-5)**(-4)**2
>>> print(x,y)
152587890625 152587890625
```